# src/main/java-generated not showing up on project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, directory, project-explorer

I was wondering why Eclipse is not picking up my folder I just created. resources folder is showing as `src/main/resources`, but my `java-generated` folder is not showing up as src/main/java-generated. I tried right-clicking my project and refreshing and restarting the Eclipse but no luck.

[Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKJkO.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's right there. The contents of Source Folders are arranged to present them to you as Java types, not a plain file hierarchy.